# Regular expression for extracting date

Tags: regex, bash, sh

I a regular expression to match a date on the form `01/Jan/2000:23:59:59`. I managed to match the pattern using Notepad++'s regex interpreter, using the following regex:

```
[1-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

Unfortunately, I **need** to do this with bash. AWK is not an option right now, I'm afraid. So, I tried to convert the above regex into something that bash would interpret in the same way. Thus far, I've come up with this:

```
[1-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}/(19|20)[0-9]\{2\}:[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

The full command I'm using is

```
expr "$line" : '\([1-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}/(19|20)[0-9]\{2\}:[0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]\)'
```

where `$line` contains the string out of which I need to extract the date. Unfortunately my bash version of the regex doesn't work. I have tried different things, like escaping `/` and `:`, but I can't seem to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note that your regex will also match `39/Foo/2099:99:59:59`, which is arguably not a valid date... It also would seem it will not match `1/Jan/2013:12:00:00`, which is a valid date, but lacks the leading zero on the day number. I would suggest that regular expressions may not be the most efficient way to validate date-formatted strings...

Comment: Thanks for the concern, but those cases doesn't apply in this case; I can assume that the date will be correct and on the same form throughout the document I'm parsing, and I can assume that is hasn't been tampered with. I will keep this in mind though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem was your first pattern [1-3]. It should be [0-3].

```
[[ $DATE =~ [0-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] ]]
```

Also, on some earlier versions of Bash you have to store it on a variable:

```
RE='[0-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
[[ $DATE =~ $RE ]]
```

Example:

```
> DATE='01/Jan/2000:23:59:59'
> [[ $DATE =~ [0-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] ]] && echo Match.
Match.
```

Bash 3.0:

```
> echo "$BASH_VERSION"
3.00.0(1)-release
> DATE='01/Jan/2000:23:59:59'
> RE='[0-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
> [[ $DATE =~ $RE ]] && echo Match.
Match.
```

If you want to apply it on a loop, you can have something like this:

```
RE='[0-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]'
while read -r LINE; do
    [[ $LINE =~ $RE ]] && echo "Match: $LINE"
done < date_list.txt
```

By the way, if you want to exactly match the whole word only use add `^` and `$` at the beginning and the end of pattern:

```
[[ $DATE =~ ^[0-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$ ]]
```

To extract matches on the line use `()` and `BASH_REMATCH`:

```
[[ $DATE =~ .*([0-3][0-9]/[A-Z][a-z]{2}/(19|20)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]).* ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Comment: So much infotmation! Thank you very much!